# Compare two columns?

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I am trying to make a macro to do the following:

1. Click button, which opens a multi-file open dialog box
2. Save the original file as a new filename
3. Create a results tab in the new filename.

The above 3 I have working, though it may not be pretty.

Here is where I get stuck:

I want to compare a specific column in wb1 against a specific column in wb2.  The columns will fluctuate in length and they will be different lengths between the two workbooks. Also, the two opened files will always have different names. Then, I want to paste the cells from wb1 that do not appear in wb2 in column A of wb3 on the results page.

```
Option Explicit
Sub opening_multiple_file()
    
Dim i As Integer
    
'Opening File dialog box
    
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Enabling multiple files select
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    
    'Only Excel files can be selected
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
    
    If .Show = True Then
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            'Opening selected file
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
        Next i
    End If
        
End With

Call save_as

End Sub

Sub save_as()
   
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks("Anomaly List Compare Master.xlsm")
wbk.Sheets("Start").Activate

Dim FileName As Variant

'Displaying the saveas dialog box
FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Fault_Report_VEHICLENUMBER_MM_DD_YYYY", _
    "Excel files,*.xls*", 1, "Select your folder and filename")
    
'Save the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName

Call CreateSheet

End Sub
        
Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Results"
    End With
Call Macro1
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim bothcolumns As Range, i As Integer
    Set bothcolumns = Selection
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wb3 As Workbook
    For Each wb1 In Application.Workbooks
        If wb1.Name Like "SV_Report*" Then
            Set wb1 = wb1
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no SV_Report file opened.  Please try again..."
            End
        End If
    For Each wb2 In Application.Workbooks
        If wb2.Name Like "PPO*" Then
            Set wb2 = wb2
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no PPO file opened.  Please try again..."
            End
        End If
    For Each wb3 In Application.Workbooks
        If wb3.Name Like "Fault_Report*" Then
            Set wb3 = wb3
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no Fault_Report file opened.  Please try again..."
            End
        End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          
    For Each rngMyCell In wb1.Sheets("Test Fault Report").Range("A5:A500")
        lngArrayCount = lngArrayCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve varDataMatrix(1 To lngArrayCount)
        varDataMatrix(lngArrayCount) = rngMyCell
    Next rngMyCell
    
    lngArrayCount = 0
    
    For Each rngMyCell In wb2.Sheets("Static").Range("B2:B500")
        lngArrayCount = lngArrayCount + 1
        If rngMyCell.Value <> varDataMatrix(lngArrayCount) Then
           GoTo QuitRoutinue
        End If
    Next rngMyCell
    
    'If we get here both datasets have matched.
    Set wb1 = Nothing
    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Erase varDataMatrix() 'Deletes the varible contents, free some memory
    MsgBox "Data is the same.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
    
QuitRoutinue:

    Set wb1 = Nothing
    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("A2:A500")
    Paste varDataMatrix()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Erase varDataMatrix() 'Deletes the varible contents, free some memory
    
End Sub
```